# Warning: filectime(): stat failed for path

Tags: php, str-replace

I am trying to get the date in which a file was modified or created with PHP. To do this I am using **[filectime](http://php.net/manual/es/function.filectime.php)** function but it is giving me always the following error:

> Warning: filectime(): stat failed for path

where path is the route in which I have stored the file.

The route is something similar to this:

```
http://MYIP/documents/animals document 1.pdf
http://MYIP/documents/animals document 2.pdf
...
```

and I have to replace the url to codify the spaces of the file:

```
$path= str_replace(' ', '%20', $path);
```

If I do this I can use a link to open this file on my browser but it shows the warning that I have put before if I try to use the same path on `filectime` function.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php: _“Supports stat(): No”_ – you simply can not use this for HTTP URLs.

Comment: _“I am trying to get the date in which a file was modified or created with PHP”_ – so use a file system path, not an HTTP URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ***filectime*** function expects a string path as a parameter. It is just a wrapper function over the usage of Posix ***stat*** system call.

The system call:

> int stat(**const char *pathname**, struct stat *buf);

So, it expects a parameter as though it's on your filesystem. The URL gets encoded to have a neat white-space-less identifier on the server side to execute appropriate scripts.

Don't bother with that "codification"! Just use a standard string path as you'd use on your UNIX shell, *relative to the script directory.*

In this case, just provide the right path to the PHP function!

```
filectime("documents/animals document 2.pdf");
```

Comment: _“You need escape sequences for the white spaces in the path”_ – no you don’t, not in the file system.

Comment: @CBroe Ah! Yup, you're right! Thanks for the correction! I was still in the context of the UNIX shell while typing that sentence...   :P

Comment: @varun But the IP is mine but external so I had to access the file with the path: `IP/animals/animals document 2.pdf`.

Comment: @varun Finally I downloaded all files to my local network to have access to them using `filectime` function. I could not find any way using remote http path.